# How to setup the Client IDs of GoogleSignin Configuration in react-native-community google-signin?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, react-native-ios

Following the [documentation guide](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin), there are 2 client ids namely webClientId and iosClientId.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWs5q.png

1. What is the purpose of having a webClientId and iosClientId?
2. Does the iosClientId open up inside the app?
3. On the other hand, does the webClientId open up outside the app in system browser?
4. How do I wire up those 2 client ids in the google developers
   console?